# c# .net 6.0 windows service - httpclient calls after a period throws timeout exception

Tags: c#, windows-services, httpclient

I have a .Net 6.0 windows service which is sending data to an api every few seconds. The windows service works fine for a period of time. However, after a while maybe 24 hours it suddenly starts logging timeout exceptions, and continues to do so. To resolve the issue I have to restart the windows service.

Here is my code doing the API call

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 
        
        public static void SetTimeout(int timeout, int poolConnectionLifeTime)
        {
            var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler
            {
                PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(poolConnectionLifeTime) 
            };
            client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
            TokenRetriever.Log.Info("Auth API http client initialised");
        }      

        public async Task<string> ExecuteGetAndReturnResponse(Dictionary<string, string> requestParams, string url)
        {
            string responseReturned = string.Empty;

            try
            {

                using (var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestParams)))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                       
                        using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                        {
                            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                            {
                                responseReturned = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                               
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        responseReturned = $"ERROR: - {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}";
                        TokenRetriever.Log.Info($"Response returned {responseReturned}");
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex) when (ex.InnerException is TimeoutException)
            {
               TokenRetriever.Log.Error("Fetching token Timed out: " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                // Handle cancellation.
               TokenRetriever.Log.Error("Task Cancellation fetching token error: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return responseReturned;
        }
```

I have tried setting the PooledConnectionLifetime to 2 minutes (configurable).
I have also overriden the default 100 seconds timeout (configurable).
The windows service calls 3 different APIs (3 seperate classes) - each one has its own static httpclient instance.
Im running out of ideas - any suggestions

Comment: I don't see `SetTimeout` being called. Can you please show how/when it is called.

Comment: Hi, this is called once on startup from program.cs. The value passed in is from the app settings.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the instantiations of your `static HttpClient` to the following

```cs
private static HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(new SocketsHttpHandler
            {
                PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(poolConnectionLifeTime) 
            });
```

If you are calling `SetTimeout` from Program.cs (I'm not sure what you're doing there) then those changes will not be applied in this class as you are creating a new `HttpClient` with the default `SocketsHttpHandler` object.